# Как правильно: коморка или каморка?

Tags: орфография, выбор-варианта

Только что обнаружил два варианта написания одного слова:
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/коморка](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0);
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/каморка](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0).
А какой все-таки правильный?
Если я напишу, к примеру, "коморка папы Карло", это будет считаться ошибкой?

Answer (score 4):

**Если Пушкин написал "коморка", то этого достаточно, чтобы появилось желание ознакомиться с историей этого слова, разве нет?**

В словаре Ушакова приводится два варианта: ***каморка и коморка***. https://slovar.cc/rus/ushakov/406569.html

**О словаре Ушакова**

Работа над толковым словарем русского языка началась в 20-е годы, и основную роль в этом  выполнял Дмитрий Николаевич Ушаков. Составление словаря продолжалось длительное время – **с 1928 по 1940 год.**

Слова ***камера*** употребляется в русском языке с Петровского времени, но написание его было неустоявшимся: *камора/камара/ комара/комора*.

Это слово (греческое по происхождению со значением "свод")  встречается **и в других славянских языках, причем тоже с вариантами**. Например, в чешском язык komora — это только техническая камера, в русском языке такой термин также использовался.

Поэтому **колебания при написании корневой гласной** и в слове ***каморка/коморка***  (в безударной позиции) наблюдались длительное время и отражены в словаре Ушакова. **Однако в 1956 году к Правилам орфографии был приложен словарь,** где за этим словом было закреплена окончательная форма — ***каморка***.

**ОТВЕТ**

Если я напишу, к примеру, "коморка папы Карло", это будет считаться ошибкой? – **Да, будет считаться ошибкой**. ***Каморка*** с 1956 года пишется с корневой гласной А (варианты не допускаются).

Исключением может быть **авторское написание**, сохраненное в изданных ранее книгах.

Comment: Не поняла, при чём здесь Пушкин?

Comment: @Людмила, уважаемая Jasmin иронизирует над моим ответом. У меня – Алексей Толстой, у нее – Пушкин.

Comment: @Niemand  Пушкин не у меня, а у себя. А если вы потрудитесь открыть ссылку из вопроса (это нетрудно),  то Пушкин будет еще и в словаре, где его цитируют: "Готов принять в моей коморке любезного гостя — но сам из коморки не выду". А. С. Пушкин, Письмо В. Ф. Одоевскому,  И отвечаю я автору вопроса, а вы мой интерес  к теме почему-то приписываете своей персоне.

Comment: Не-не-не. Не автору вы отвечаете. Потому что у автора: "коморка папы Карло". Так вот-с: любая другая каморка может быть и "коморкой", а каморка папы Карло – только "каморкой". И никаких словарей не нужно, и даже Пушкин не нужен.

Comment: Внимательно читайте мой ответ. С 1956 года правильно писать "каморка". Если у А. Толстого написано именно так, то править его и писать "коморка" будет ОШИБКОЙ. С Пушкиным сложнее: иногда используется авторское написание "коморка", а иногда вносится изменение, например: https://godliteratury.ru/projects/pismovnik-pushkin-odoevskomu

Answer (score 3):

Многие сочтут слово "коморка" либо ошибкой, либо диалектным словом, либо устаревшим написанием. Всё эти варианты могут попадать в Викисловарь, но если Вас интересует правильное современное написание, лучше сверяться с академическими словарями — толковыми и орфографическими. Я убедился, что ни в толковом словаре Кузнецова, ни в орфографическом словаре Лопатина такого слова нет.

Comment: Почему нет? Есть: http://dict.t-mm.ru/all/kamorka.html  И у Лопатина, и у Зализняка, и у Ефремовой, и у Кузнецова -  и везде каморка http://vslovare.info/slovo/tolkovjyij-slovar-efremovoij/kamorka-zh-razg/464369
https://gufo.me/dict/kuznetsov/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0
https://gufo.me/dict/zaliznyak/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: @Людмила Это недоразумение. Я утверждаю, что нет только слова "коморка". "Каморку" я и сам нашёл во всех словарях.

Answer (score 1):

В оригинале у Алексея Толстого именно "каморка". Одного этого достаточно.